# Java: Fill a matrix multi-threaded, currently no thread-safe

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm supernew to multi-threading, but I think I got the overall idea more or less. I'm trying to fill a matrix multi-threaded, but my code is clearly not thread-safe, I have duplicate columns in my matrix, which is not the case when the matrix is filled regularly. Below is an example block of code. Note that the reader is a Scanner object and someOperationOnText(someText) returns an int[100] object.

```
    int[][] mat = new int[100][100];
    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        Set<Integer>someText = new HashSet<>(reader.next());
        int lineIndex = i;
        threadPool.submit(() -> mat[lineIndex] = someOperationOnText(someText);
   }
```

Do you see any reason why this is not thread-safe? I can't seem to get my head around it, since the reading is done outside the thread-pool, I didn't think it would be at risk.

Thanks a lot for any debugging tips!
Grts

Comment: The problem seems hiding behind `someOperationOnText`, post it.

Comment: And posting your `input` `output` helps.

Comment: Why do you call a `Set<Integer>` (a set of numbers!) `someText` ? Clearly it's not text. And what does `reader.next()` return? And please describe what you means with "duplicate columns in my matrix" - provide some sample input and expected output.

Comment: Hm okay fair enough, I will try to make a small example because putting all the code will be a bit of an overkill. Was hoping there was something superobvious already by looking at this block :) Regarding the questions already above; the Set<Integer> is a set of hashed values of readed text and that's what reader.next() returns. With duplicate columns I mean that some columns are exactly the same, which seems to point at the fact that the program is using the same text to assign values to different columns. I will get back here later if I manage to put it in a small example.

Comment: where do you increment `lineIndex` ? If you could do it atomically (using atomic integer), you should be able to ensure that one of the 2-D indexes is safe. As others suggested, the other index is controlled in `someOperationOnText()` so the answer lies there

Comment: Actually your comment helped me to find the right query to solve the issue. I added "final int lineIndex = i;" instead of "int lineIndex".

Comment: ah and also made the called method synchronized. Sorry, i will not give a toy example or more details about the problem now, i'm chasing a deadline.. Thanks for all the tips here

Comment: If you make the method `someOperationOnText` synchronized, you can remove the multithreading alltogether, because that was the only thing that you did in parallel. Your code will be cleaner and better to understand without the threadpool and the submit, and just as fast.

Answer (score 1):

There is a *happens-before* between the `submit` calls and the execution of the lambda by a thread in the executor's thread pool.  (See [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html): "Memory consistency effects").  So that means the lambda will see the correct values for `someText`, `mat` and `lineIndex`.

The only thing that is not thread-safe about this is the (implied) code that uses the values in `mat` in the main thread.  Calling `shutdown()` on the executor should be sufficient ... though the javadocs don't talk about the memory consistency effects of `shutdown()` and `awaitTermination()`.

(By my reading of the [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java#ThreadPoolExecutor) for `ThreadPoolExecutor`, the `awaitTermination()` method provides a *happens-before* between the pool threads (after completion of all tasks) and the method's return.  The *happens-before* is due the use of the executor's main lock to synchronize the pool shutdown.  It is hard to see how they could implement shutdown correctly without this (or equivalent), so it is more than an "implementation artefact" ... IMO.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, accessing elements in the matrix is a very fast operation, a computing is not.

I think making access to a matrix synchronized while computing can be concurrent is a right approach for you.

```
    int[][] mat = new int[100][100];
    Object lock = new Object();
    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        Set<Integer> someText = new HashSet<>(reader.next());
        int lineIndex = i;
        threadPool.submit(() -> {
            int result = someOperationOnText(someText);
            synchronized (lock) {
                mat[lineIndex] = result;
            }
        });
    }
```